# Split LIST , filename with add domain for each filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need help with this function for split a list of filesname with add for each file the site

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

site = 'http://example.com/'

files = ['Steve.php','Jane.php','Sara.php','Mary.php','Jack.php','Bob.php']

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

result = list(chunks(files, 2))
print (result)

>>  [['Steve.php', 'Jane.php'], ['Sara.php', 'Mary.php'], ['Jack.php', 'Bob.php']]
```

but i need like here

```
1)  ',' and not ', '   ( without space )

and 

2) >> [['http://example.com/Steve.php', 'http://example.com/Jane.php'], ['http://example.com/Sara.php', 'http://example.com/Mary.php'], ['http://example.com/Jack.php', 'http://example.com/Bob.php']]
```

how i can edit this function ?

Thanks

Comment: When you print a list in Python the list elements will always be separated by ', ' (comma space). If it's just the visual aesthetic that you want to change then you'll need to build a custom string and print that

Comment: What `',' and not ', '` means?

Comment: `[[site + a, site + b] for a, b in zip(files[::2], files[1::2])]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but perhaps this is what you want:

```
site = 'http://example.com/'
files = ['Steve.php','Jane.php','Sara.php','Mary.php','Jack.php','Bob.php']

output = [[site+files[i], site+files[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(files), 2)]

print(repr(output).replace(' ', ''))
```

**Output:**

```
[['http://example.com/Steve.php','http://example.com/Jane.php'],['http://example.com/Sara.php','http://example.com/Mary.php'],['http://example.com/Jack.php','http://example.com/Bob.php']]
```

**Note:**

This will fail if the *files* list has an odd number of elements

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS !!!! THANKS OLVIN !!!!

Comment: @Montauros.r.o Clicking the check box to the left of the answer to mark is as "accepted" is preferred to saying "thanks".

Answer (score -1):

```
site = 'http://example.com/' 
files = ['Steve.php','Jane.php','Sara.php','Mary.php','Jack.php','Bob.php']  
files = [site + file for file in files] 
files = [files[i:i+2] for i in range(len(files)) if i%2 == 0]
```

The code above should do the job! I don't know what you mean by the requirement

> ',' and not ', '

That is simply how python outputs the file.

Comment: Thanks so much for ur help, working fine, but still i dont know how to fix this:

['http://example.com/Steve.php', 'http://example.com/Jane.php']

['http://example.com/Steve.php','http://example.com/Jane.php']    without space

Comment: You are welcome! As I wrote that is simply how python outputs the result. The result, if I understood correctly, should be a list whose elements are 2-element lists. each of these 2-element list is made up of a two strings.   
Tell me why you want to have no spaces between the comma and the letter, I may come up with an answer. 
If not I ask you to accept my answer, because I need it to earn points :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not produce the OP's output requirements